# Add an item to Form.SerializeArray()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I get form input elements as follow using jquery for further processing.

```
var ctrls = $('#frmUserMst').serializeArray();
```

Occasionally i need to add some extra info into this ctrl Array. How do i do this as

it does not support `push()` or `add()` method.

This is a requirement in VS2008 MVC2 project.

**Further info:**
As disabled controls are not populated in the `serializeArray()` output, i need to add them manualy.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your extra information before you serialize the array?

Comment: yes no problem as long as it works. But adding later will be really helpful.

Comment: Temporarily make the disabled controls enabled, serialize the array, then disable them again. If you must add a new one to the array, use `.push({"name":"inputname","value":"inputvalue"})` on the output of `.serializeArray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.serializeArray` outputs an array of objects. Each object has two keys: `name` and `value`. `name` represents the input name, and `value` represents the input value. Therefore, you can add another item to the array by adding another object to the array that matches the other objects.

```
var ctrls = $("#frmUserMst").serializeArray();
ctrls.push({
    "name": "myinputname",
    "value": "myinputvalue"
});
```

The input doesn't have to exist for you to add a value to that array.

Comment: Thanks kevin but i dont get push() as intelisense.